Failed to respond from Telegram bot linked to google sheet script
I am trying to build a Telegram bot to my students. It should work with the student to get his certificate verification. The student send his Id and to the bot then the bot respond with some data about this certificate (id, student name, description).
Firstly I do small test schedule in Google sheet like this:

Then I go to the script editor in google sheet and I add the following code and for sure I add the bot token and webAppUrl and etc. Also I set the Webhook.
Now when I send a message for telegram bot, I have not any response from the bot. However I see the message in the Webhook Api data.

Finally, This is my code:


var token = "";
var telegramUrl= "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + token;
var webAppUrl = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/****/exec"; // FILL IN YOUR GOOGLE WEB APP ADDRESS
var SheetID = "1O*****Rw4"; // FILL IN THE ID OF YOUR SPREADSHEET
//var adminID = 11111;   // 4. Fill in your own Telegram ID for debugging

  

function doPost(e) {
  try {
    var stringJson = e.postData.getDataAsString();
    var updates = JSON.parse(stringJson);
    if (updates.message.text) {
      sendText(updates.message.chat.id, GetDataFromIDSheet(updates.message.text));
    }
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log("Error in doPost: " + error.message);
    // Handle the error (e.g., send an error message to the user)
  }
}


function getSheet1(){
  var rangeName = 'Sheet1!A2:C';
  var rows = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(SheetID, rangeName).values;
  return rows;
}


function GetDataFromIDSheet(IDbarang){
  var data = getSheet1(); 
  for (var row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
    if(data[row][0]==IDbarang){ 
      return "certificate Id : " + data[row][0] + "\n" +
             "Full Name : " + data[row][1] + "\n" + 
             "Description  : " + data[row][2];
    }
  }
  return "Not Found." +"\n"+ "Some thing wrong.";
}

function sendText(chatid,text,replymarkup){
var data = {
    method: "post",
    payload: {
      method: "sendMessage",
      chat_id: String(chatid),
      text: text,
      parse_mode: "HTML",
      reply_markup: JSON.stringify(replymarkup)
    }
  };
  UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.telegram.org/bot' + token + '/', data);
}



Can any one help me to solove this
and thanks alot.
Update:

I am trying to do some tests and now I know the problem is with the doPost function is not triggered. I checed my token is correct, also the webappUrl I think it's also corect. I don't know what the problem

